# Is there a digital version of the CP/M T/Maker manual available?

Tags: cp-m, manual

I have a CP/M emulator running on a Raspberry Pi.  I managed to run the old circa 1979 [T/Maker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T/Maker) program, but I don't have a manual.  Any thoughts on where I can find one?

Answer (score 3):

[WinworldPC](https://winworldpc.com/) has a section for [T/Maker 4 for DOS](https://winworldpc.com/product/t-maker/4x) which includes the [4.03 Manuals](https://winworldpc.com/download/41e44be1-63c5-11ed-aca0-0200008a0da4).

Not sure how much it changed from the version you're using (*1), but it might be worth a look.

---

*1 - might be helpful to add at least the version you're looking for to the question

Comment: Thank You! I am using version 4.01, and the manual you pointed me to is quite close.